# Windows 10 cannot start, like in endless loop

Tags: windows-10, boot

Somewhat polished version from Google Translate:

Simply, from one day to the next, my notebook started with a very annoying problem that I had never encountered before. I'll detail some of the problems and things I've done to try to solve the problem, but to no avail.

The notebook does not boot. It goes through the bios and stays in an endless loop on the Windows 10 screen (the one with the spinning dots). It does not restart or anything, it just stays in that infinite loop (I've left hours and hours, and nothing).

From time to time I get to the same screen, but with the message "preparing automatic repair". Likewise, it stays infinitely on this screen. As crazy as it sounds, after restarting (manually) several, several and several times, the notebook can "turn on" as if nothing had happened. But guess what happens if you turn it off and on again? That's right, the problem comes back.

I've already put a bootable pen drive (which I'm sure works, because I've already formatted two computers with it, including the notebook itself a while ago), and trying to boot the pen drive (the message "press any key to boot from usb "appears, and I press any key), the Windows logo appears and stays in the same case: loading infinite.

I already removed the SSD from the notebook (it is the only storage unit) and tried to boot from USB to see if this loading freeze was happening for something corrupted on the disk, but no, I fall into the same case. After trying hard, I was able to boot the pen drive and format the notebook. However, the problem persisted. I'm very confused about this and honestly I do not know what to try anymore. I would like help with this problem because I could not find anything on the internet that could help me.

---

Original post:

Simplesmente, de um dia para o outro, meu notebook começou com um problema muito chato, que nunca tinha deparado antes. Eu vou detalhar alguns dos problemas e coisas que já fiz para tentar solucionar o problema, mas sem sucesso.

- O notebook não inicializa. Ele passa pela bios e fica num loop sem
  fim na tela do Windows 10 (aquela que tem os pontinhos girando). Ele
  não reinicia nem nada, apenas fica nesse loop infinito (já deixei
  horas e horas, e nada). 
  De vez em quando consigo entrar na mesma
  tela, mas com a mensagem "preparing automatic repair". Da mesma
  forma, fica infinitamente nessa tela. Por mais doido que pareça, após
  reiniciar (manualmente) várias, várias e várias vezes, o notebook
  consegue "ligar", como se nada tivesse acontecido. Mas adivinha o que
  acontece se desligá-lo e ligá-lo de novo? Isso mesmo, o erro volta.
  Já coloquei um pen drive bootavel (que tenho total certeza que
  funciona, pois hoje mesmo já formatei dois computadores com ele,
  inclusive o próprio notebook um tempo atrás), e ao tentar dar boot
  pelo pen drive (a mensagem "press any key to boot from usb" aparece,
  e eu aperto qualquer tecla), a logo do windows aparece e fica no
  mesmo caso: loading infinito. Já removi o SSD do notebook (é a única
  unidade de armazenamento) e tentei dar boot pelo USB, para ver se
  este congelamento no loading estava acontecendo por alguma coisa
  corrompida no disco, mas não, caio no mesmo caso. Depois de tentar
  muito, consegui dar boot pelo pen drive e formatar o notebook.
  Entretanto, o erro persistiu. Eu estou muito confuso sobre este erro,
  e honestamente não sei mais o que tentar. Gostaria muito de ajuda com
  este problema, porque não consegui achar nada na internet que pudesse
  me ajudar.

No mais, agradeço.

Comment: Use english please.

Comment: Automatic repair can sometimes take a very long time, let it set overnight when you get the automatic repair screen.

Comment: Perhaps something wrong with your RAM. Did you get some BSOD error codes?

Comment: Try an alternative operating system, e.g. a Live Linux distro on USB. If that works, you've likely eliminated hardware as an issue, and you might even want to stay with Linux.